# Display ASP.MVC view in CKEditor dialog window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

I created a plugin with a custom dialog window.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('imggallery',
{
init: function (editor) {
    var pluginName = 'imggallery';
    editor.ui.addButton('Image',
        {
            label: 'Add image',
            command: 'OpenWindow',
            icon: CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('imggallery') + 'lightbulb.gif'
        });

    editor.addCommand('OpenWindow', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('simpleLinkDialog'));

    var html2 = "<h1>This is a heading</h1>";

    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('simpleLinkDialog', function (editor) {
        return {
            title: 'LinkProperties',
            minWidth: 400,
            minHeight: 200,
            contents:
            [
                {
                    id: 'general',
                    label: 'Settings',
                    elements:
                    [
                        {
                            type: 'html',
                            html: html2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
    });
}
});
```

My question is: Is it possible to somehow display ASP.MVC view in window content?
When I assign html2 to elements property the text is shown without formatting (plain text).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's plain text and not a H1 tag that is formatted to look like plain text? There's a big difference :). The CKE dialogs reset most of the standard browser styles so that elements appear like plain text, even though they are not.

As for the MVC view, I would recommend that you add an iframe within the CKE dialog and display the page normally there. Then you can control or get/set values from the iframe using JavaScript. It will be a bit tricky, but should work.

```
var html2 = '<iframe id="DialogIframe" src="/MyController/MyView?foo=bar"></iframe>';
```

The other option is to use something like jQuery to `$.get()` the HTML and then use it, should be relatively simple if you have worked with ajax before. If not, here's a good chance to start! :)